# How to adjust brightness on windows 7 Laptop

Tags: windows-7, brightness

I have installed Windows 7 on my PC. I noticed that display is too bright which effect my eyes during working.

But I didn't get setting for adjusting brightness. Can anyone tell where to find **Brightness Adjustment Setting** in Windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have keys marked as shown below on your keyboard.

[image]

Using them in combination with <kbd>Fn</kbd> should help you adjust the brightness of your screen.

Note : *Keys on your keyboard maybe on different location depending your laptop brand and model*

However you can use a third party utility called [f.lux](https://justgetflux.com/) which does more than that, *not getting any money for promotion:(*

Comment: function key (fn) is not working properly, Its been damaged

Comment: @Pallavi You could try OnScreenKeyboard `osk` to get `Fn` keys functionality, but what is the make and model of your laptop

Comment: yeah thats a good Idea

Answer (score 0):

Control Panel **->** Hardware and Sound **->** Power Options **->** Edit Plan Settings   for plan specific, or just in power options on the bottom

Answer (score 0):

Check the brightness level in the Control Panel, plus your laptop should have a funtion key to adjust the brightness .

[image]